# Partial line from cpp file ending up in output file - haunted code?

Tags: c++, c, file, printf

I'm sorry, it would be extremely difficult to make a fully reproducible version of the error --- so please bare with my schematic code.

This program retrieves information from a web page, processes it, and saves output to an ASCII file.  I also have a 'log' file (`FILE *theLog`---contained within a `Manager` object) for reporting errors, etc.

---

Some background methods:

```
// Prints string to log file
void Manager::logEntry(const string lstr) {
    if( theLog != NULL ) { fprintf(theLog, "%s", lstr.c_str()); }
}

// Checks if file with given name already exists
bool fileExists(const string fname) {
    FILE *temp;
    if( temp = fopen(fname.c_str(), "r") ) { 
        fclose(temp);
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
}

// Initialize file for writing (some components omitted)...
bool initFile(FILE *&oFile, const string fname) {
    if(oFile = fopen(fname.c_str(), "w") ) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}
```

---

The stuff causing trouble:

```
// Gets data from URL, saves to file 'dataFileName', input control flag 'foreCon'
//                     stu is some object that has string which i want
bool saveData(Manager *man, Stuff *stu, string dataFileName, const int foreCon) {
    char logStr[CHARLIMIT_LARGE];          // CHARLIMIT_LARGE = 2048
    sprintf(logStr, "Saving Data...\n");
    man->logEntry( string(logStr) );       // This appears fine in 'theLog' correctly

    string data = stu->getDataPrefixStr() + getDataFromURL() + "\n";        // fills 'data' with stuff
    data += stu->getDataSuffixStr();

    if( fileExists(dataFileName) ) {
        sprintf(logStr, "save file '%s' already exists.", dataFileName.c_str() );
        man->logEntry( string(logStr) );
        if( foreCon == -1 ) {
            sprintf(logStr, "foreCon = %d, ... exiting.", foreCon);        // LINE 'A' : THIS LINE ENDS UP IN OUTPUT FILE
            tCase->logEntry( string(logStr) );
            return false;
        } else {
            sprintf(logStr, "foreCon = %d, overwriting file.", foreCon);   // LINE 'B' : THIS LINE ENDS UP IN LOG FILE
            tCase->logEntry( string(logStr) );
        }                                                                                                 
    }

    // Initialize output file
    FILE *outFile;
    if( !initFile(outFile, dataFileName) ) {
        sprintf(logStr, "couldn't initFile '%s'", dataFileName.c_str());
        tCase->logEntry( string(logStr) );
        return false;
    }

    fprintf(outFile, "%s", data.c_str());                 // print data to output file

    if( fclose(outFile) != EOF) {
        sprintf(logStr, "saved to '%s'", dataFileName.c_str());
        tCase->logEntry( string(logStr) );
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If the file already exists, AND '`int foreCon` = -1' then the code should print out line 'A' to the logFile.  If the file exists and `foreCon` != -1, the old file is overwritten with `data`.  If the file doesn't exist, it is created, and the data is written to it.

The result however, is that a broken up version of line 'A' appears in the data file AND line 'B' is printed in the log file!!!!

What the data file looks like:

```
.. exiting.20130127 161456
20130127 000000,55,17,11,0.00
20130127 010000,54,17,11,0.00
... ...
```

The second line and onward look correct, but there is an extra line that contains part of line 'A'.

Now, the REALLY WEIRD PART.  If I comment out everything in the `if( foreCon == -1) { ... }` block, then the data file looks like:

```
%d, ... exiting.20130127 161456
20130127 000000,55,17,11,0.00
20130127 010000,54,17,11,0.00
... ...
```

There is still an extra line, but it is the LITERAL CODE copied into the data file.

I think there is a poltergeist in my code.  I don't understand how any of this could happen.

---

Edit:   I've tried printing to console the `data` string, and it gives the same messed up values: i.e. `%d, ... exiting.20130127 161456` - so it must be something about the `string` instead of the `FILE *`

Comment: Do you compile your code including debug symbols? Looks to me like a \0 is missing somewhere.

Comment: scary... before you know it, it'll come after you with a knife.

Comment: It is a *string literal* that you are seeing which means that you are somehow peaking into the data segment.

Comment: What's the significance of 'cpp' in the title of the question?  Is this meant to be C or C++?  Avoid tagging with both languages.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 'cpp' to signify that *literally* a line from the code is ending up in the output, instead of just the string in a line.  Both C and C++ because its c++, but I'm using c methods (i.e. sprintf, fprintf ...) instead of streams.  Is that still poor form?

Comment: Hardcoded string like `"this is a string"` are (in most systems) stored in a special part of the executable called "the data segment" which is then copied or mapped into memory. That's how code is getting into run-time memory with a compiled language.

Comment: @dmckee okay, thanks.  So that means that the `string data` is being filled improperly?

Comment: No, it means that you are accessing a string literal incorrectly at some point...overwriting a terminating `\0` or something. It's hard to say exactly what. Look carefully at your `char*` manipulations.

Comment: I only use `char *`s with sprintf, and the `CHARLIMIT_LARGE` is much larger than I ever use.... how else could I overwrite a `\0` --- I've never explicitly added a `\0` - do I need to be?

Comment: I've added the line `cout << "TEST: " << stu->getDataPrefixStr() << getDataFromURL() << endl;` - and now, included in the console output are two extra instances of `EST:` ... what the hell?!

Comment: @zhermes So what do those two functions look like?

Comment: @molbdnilo ugly and complicated --- but I'll try looking around there, good idea.

Comment: @molbdnilo even if I comment out those function calls, the same type of problems are occurring.

Comment: @dmckee `getDataPrefixStr()` ends up returning a string which starts with something like `string retStr = COMCHAR + " file created on ...";` such that `const char COMCHAR = '#';`.  Could the `COMCHAR` be the problem??

Comment: @molbdnilo it seems that when I remove `COMCHAR` from the function - everything works fine!  Any ideas why?

Comment: @zhermes You can't add characters and strings like that. You're adding  35 (the ASCII for "#") to the address of " file created on ... ", i.e.  getDataPrefixStr() is whatever starts 35 characters from the start of that string.

Comment: The issue that @molbdnilo just identified should result in a compiler warning if you have them turned all the way up. (Something along the lines of *"expression makes a pointer from integer without cast"* or the reverse.)

Comment: Thanks dmckee and @molbdnilo, I've changed `const char COMCHAR = '#';` to `const char COMCHAR[] = "#";` and the usage to `string retStr = string(COMCHAR) + " ... ";`.  That seems to be working.  Regarding compiler warnings:  I just added `-wall` to my makefile... I'll be trying to fix the 100 new warnings for the next few hours ;)

Comment: @dmckee Since the literal string already can decay to  a pointer, the addition would be valid if the string were at least 35 characters long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer based on your latest comment:

> getDataPrefixStr() ends up returning a string which starts with
>   something like string retStr = COMCHAR + " file created on ..."; such
>   that const char COMCHAR = '#';. Could the COMCHAR be the problem??

You can't add characters and string literals (which are arrays of `char`, not `string`s) like that.

You're adding 35 (the ASCII for "#") to the address of " file created on ... ", i.e. getDataPrefixStr() is whatever starts 35 characters from the start of that string. Since all literal strings are stored together in the same data area, you'll get strings from the program in the output.

Instead, you cold do

```
   const string COMCHAR = "*"; 
   string retStr = COMCHAR + " file created on ...";
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that `logStr` is too short and that it is causing data to be overwritten in other buffers (did you double check `CHARLIMIT_LARGE`?). You can diagnose this by commenting all writes to `logStr` (`sprintf`) and see if `data` is still corrupted. In general, your code is vulnerable to this if a user can set `dataFileName` (to be a very long string); use `snprintf` or `ostringstream` instead.

Otherwise, I would guess that either `stu->getDataPrefixStr()` or `getDataFromURL()` are returning corrupted results or return type `char*` instead of `string`. Try printing these values to the console directly to see if they are corrupted or not. If they return a `char*`, then `data = stu->getDataPrefixStr() + getDataFromURL()` will have undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

```
if( temp = fopen(fname.c_str(), 'r') ) {
```

should be

```
if( temp = fopen(fname.c_str(), "r") ) {
```

Comment: I would say that such an error causes undefined behaviour and then it could have been the answer.